# Cannot resolve (or import) Android widget OnEditorActionListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, listener, actionlistener

I am new to coding and keep getting errors when trying to use **OnEditorActionListener** to help perform an action once the user inputs data into EditText and presses "Go" on the softkeyboard.  I have searched and most solutions offered assume that OnEditorActionListener is already imported.

Articles used as a guide to generate my own code:

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Basic-Event-Listeners

My XML Code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCurrentBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true">
        <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

My Java Code (snippet):

```
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener; 

EditText editTextListener = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCurrentBalance);
editTextListener.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){...});
```

**First Error:** " import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener; " gives me an error that says "Unused Import Statement" and the whole line of code is grey'd out.

**Second Error:** " Cannot Resolve Symbol 'setOnEditorActionListener' "

**Fix Attempt:** When I press CTRL + I, I get a message "No methods to implement have been found".

Appreciate any help!

**UPDATE:** My Java Code for the OnEditorActionListener was outside of the OnCreate method brackets.  Once put inside, the errors cleared up.

Comment: Your first error is just a warning, meaning it's like a tip. It's telling you the `android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;` is unused, meaning you can remove it.

Comment: Highlight the text that has the error and press ALT+ENTER , that should do it.

Comment: Tried ALT+Enter on "setOnEditorActionListener" and got a message to insert "App Indexing API Code" after I clicked it inserted a lot of code at the bottom but the original error still persists.

Comment: Could you please share whole list of imports from your class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO

**1st error**: well this is actually not an error, it's just a warning your IDE is giving you meaning you have imported a class you are not using. It's a good practice to remove any unused imports (Ctrl + Alt + O in Android Studio)

**2nd error**: I believe this one is popping up because you haven't imported EditText class, but I'm not sure

Anyway, take a loot at this

```
//We are import the classes you need here
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

//here is just the onCreate method from an Activity, 
//I have left out most of the boilerplate code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //make sure you are placing the code in onCreate method, or
    //a method called from onCreate, or any method other life cycle 
    //method that suits yours needs
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*snip*/

        //grabing the EditText object by it's ID you defined in the layout file
        //I have renamed the object to "editText" because "listener" 
        //suffix made no sense here, it's an EditText class you are 
        //crating, which is not a listener 
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCurrentBalance);

        //here we are creating a new anonymous class and setting to
        //trigger when an "Editor Action" happens on editTextListener
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                //do something here
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Anonymous classes are just a simpler way of creating a new class if we don't intent to reuse that class somewhere else ie. it's specific to your current need

Hope this helps :) and good luck learning Android and Java

Comment: If this was a missing import statement for editText, the error would be on EditText, not on the one he indicated

Comment: Thank you Antonio and AbAppletic!  After carefully reading the code snippet provided, I noticed that my OnEditorActionListener section of code was outside of the OnCreate method brackets.  Once I put it inside the errors went away.